# java swt create folder and save file

Tags: java, csv, file-io, swt

In my project i display some data in a table. I have also written code to save the table as csv.
Now i want that as soon as data starts coming from serial port a folder is automatically created on the particular date and csv file is saved with a default name. Also if possible to have the feature of Save and Save As.

```
public String saveFileDlg() {
    boolean done = false;
    FileDialog fileDlg = new FileDialog(myGUI.shell, SWT.SAVE);
    fileDlg.setText("Save");
    fileDlg.setFilterExtensions(FILTER_EXTNS);
    fileDlg.setFilterNames(FILTER_NAMES);
    fileDlg.setFileName("new");
    String fileSelected = null;
    while(!done) {
        fileSelected = fileDlg.open();
        if(fileSelected == null) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            myGUI.FILTER_PATH = fileDlg.getFilterPath();
            System.out.println(fileSelected);
            File file = new File(fileSelected);
            if(file.exists()) {
                MessageBox msgBox = new MessageBox(fileDlg.getParent(), SWT.ICON_WARNING|SWT.YES|SWT.NO);
                msgBox.setMessage(fileSelected + " " + "already exists. Do you want to replace it?");
                int response = msgBox.open();
                if(response == SWT.YES) {
                    done = true;
                }
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return fileSelected;
}
```

After getting the "fileSelected" i call the csvWriter method to save.

Comment: So what part of this is causing you a problem? It is not at all clear what you expect as an answer.

Comment: how to create a folder with system date as name and then save the csv file in that folder. Also how can i implement both "Save" and "Save as" in my code.